# How to sell or convert recently delisted coins on Binance?

Tags: exchanges, binance

Binance recently delisted SERUM. I still have some left on my account and I want to convert it into another currency. Is it possible to do this and if so, how? I read the following statement: "Delisted tokens may be converted into stablecoins on behalf of users, after 2023-11-22 03:00 (UTC). The proceeds will be credited to users’ Binance account.". Source: [Binance announcement of delisting several coins](https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/binance-will-delist-snm-srm-and-yfii-on-2023-08-22-f43511a4c1d347a8a2dd1efbdd2fe716)

Does this mean that it is impossible to exchange/sell/convert SERUM until the given date?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, based on the information provided in the Binance announcement, it does mean that you won't be able to exchange, sell, or convert your SERUM tokens on Binance until after the given date